# Call Authenticated action method from Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, basic-authentication

I have implemented one MVC application with Basic implementation as per [this](http://www.ryadel.com/en/http-basic-authentication-asp-net-mvc-using-custom-actionfilter/)

Now when I call this action method from my Webform application using AJAX, it did not asking for credentials and throwing an 401 error.

This is my ajax function:

```
  function testSS()
        {
            $.ajax({

                url: 'http://localhost:52099/Controller/Sample',
                type: 'GET',                  
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#ctl00_cphPageContent_SSlbl12").val(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr);
                }
            });
        }
```

How can I call authenticated method from webform project?

Thanks!

Comment: When you call the methods you need to add en authentication header, your code probably miss that

Comment: authentication header from ajax call?

Comment: The authentication code you linked check if there is an authentication header. If the webform user is logged, you should use the basic asp.net authentication ; the code you use is meant to protect the webservice while having anonymous users. How it works depends on the code you wrote to call the web service. Also, note if you let an anonymous access to your mvc action, it will probably be insecure event with this authentication

Comment: I have added my ajax function. Can you please guide what can be improved in this except headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work, you need to add an `Authorization` header, containing base64-encoded login and password.

To encode base 64, you can use [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa)

```
var authHeader = window.btoa("login:password");
```

Now, you can add this header (see [$.ajax documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:52099/Controller/Sample',
    headers: { Authorization: authHeader },
    type: 'GET',                  
    success: function (result) {
        $("#ctl00_cphPageContent_SSlbl12").val(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr);
    }
});
```

Please note this will not be very secure, because login/password are known from the client, and sent in an easily readable way, so very easy to be found by an attacker.

If the webform page and MVC action are in the same project, and the user is ogged on your website, you should probably use the asp.net `[Authorize]` attribute instead : it will check the auth cookie, and not rely on a login/password, it's much more secure.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But both are different project so I have used this authentication. Is there any other secure way? I will go through it.

Comment: You can still use the asp.net cookie, but you'll need more configuration. Look at this article : https://www.codeproject.com/tips/438319/sharing-authentication-cookie-between-two-asp-net